# GPIO esd protection

Tags: i2c, gpio, esd

I came across NXP app note highlighting esd protection for GPIO pins. I found two different schemes for digital IO and I2C as given below:

[image: Digital IO]

[image: I2C pins]

As far as I know, I2C pins are same as Uni-directional digital IO at least in terms of voltages appearing on them.

As such why is it showing two different methods for both cases? - Single diode for uni-directional protection as compared to rail to rail voltage clamp for i2c lines. (Please ignore the bi-directional thing. That's for the case when voltage swing is in both polarities.)

Will uni-directional protection method work satisfactorily for i2c lines protection?

Link to the app note: www.nxp.com/documents/leaflet/75017664.pdf

Answer (score 1):

ESD events can be in either polarity (and [testing](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/TND410-D.PDF) against it requires testing both polarities).

There are times when the bidirectional case is not appropriate, such as when one ESD diode is already in the package, or when two unidirectional devices are attached to a given pin.

The general case for ESD is to provide bidirectional protection whether that be within the IC (many communications interface devices [incorporate](http://www.ti.com/lsds/ti/interface/rs-422-products.page#) such protection)

Note that many modern devices cannot tolerate more than (V+)+0.3V to (V-)-0.3V (where V+ and V- are the power rails) which pushes us into schottky devices.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as far as I can tell, you would only use the bi-directional version if the pin can go below ground in normal use. In the unidirectional version, the diode forward conduction ties the pin to around -0.6V if it goes below ground, and to the breakdown voltage of the diode in the overvoltage case, which is fine for I2C.

Answer (score 0):

> As such why is it showing two different methods for both cases? - Single diode for uni-directional protection as compared to rail to rail voltage clamp for i2c lines. (Please ignore the bi-directional thing)

The rail-to-rail clamping method is supposed to provide lower capacitance (in comparison to the single diode clamping) as noted below the 4.1 graphic in your post. They consider I2C to be high speed compared to a normal GPIO use.

To quote [SEMTECH](http://www.semtech.com/images/datasheet/railclamp_tvs_diodes_for_high_speed_interfaces.pdf) on this:

> A popular low capacitance protection method is the
>   “rail-to-rail” technique. In this configuration, low
>   capacitance steering diodes are connected between
>   the protected line and two fixed voltage references
>   such as VCC and ground

Its also common to use this protection configuration for USB.

One downside is, that you potentially should protect Vcc separately, because you clamp the ESD pulse directly to the supply line. But you get the benefit to clamp at one diode forward voltage drop, compared to (mostly) much higher Vclamp from TVS diodes. There are some other pros/cons.